# Zabbix log trigger

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I'm using Zabbix to monitor a log file. I want to be notified whenever the regular expression 'error' has been inserted to the log.

The Item is:

```
log[/var/log/device-registry-service/DeviceRegistryService.log]
```

And this is the trigger:

```
svname1:log[/var/log/device-registry-service/DeviceRegistryService.log].iregexp(error)}=1
```

Problem is, usually when error occurs, the regex 'error' is repeating on the log's delta 10-20 times, which mean I get 10-20 mail notifications.

Can I configure it the notify me when it triggers, unless it was triggered in the last 5 minutes (or so)?

Just to make it clearer: if some arbitrary time the log delta is:

*line1

line2

error1

line3

error2

line4

error3*

I want it to trigger only once (or alternatively, configure the action to only once per hour)

Thanks!

edit:
since I want to know if any error has occurred, last() does not seem to help

Comment: Have you tried last()? Please check the documentation here : https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/triggers/expression

Comment: When an error occurs, are the "error" lines consecutive or not? If they are, you can simply uncheck "Multiple PROBLEM events generation". Another important aspect is whether there are "good" lines after "error", and whether you wish the trigger to return to OK state after some time.